# Insert into table by filtering date from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

As a overview we are trying to analyse one kind of eCommerce delivery business, where our today's business depends on last evening and today's morning orders

And our business team defined the below for any given day's business

**Evening order:** Period (previous day(Today -1) 18:00:00) to Today 01:00:00 
**Morning order:** Period Today 01:00:00 to Today 18:00:00

The below is our **order table** schema

```
consumer:
  Varchar(16), 
  timestamp Timestamp , 
  order_id Varchar(32), 
  order_item Varchar(32)
```

**sample data:**

```
 Sandeep, 2018-06-24 16:02:30,884 , l9093klk0333333330, drimmer
 Brown, 2018-06-24 18:02:40,764 , l9093klk0333333331, voucher
 kumar, 2018-06-24 00:15:10,516 , l9093klk0333333332, watch
 Jolly, 2018-06-25 08:01:15,324 , l9093klk0333333333, Tshirt
```

And the above data we clear it for every week.

```
business:
  timestamp Timestamp, 
  order_id Varchar(32), 
  orderTime(Varchar 16)
```

We like to do following **insert into business table** using **timestamp of order table**

If **Evening order** Insert into business **timestamp from order table +1 day**, order_id from order table, "Evening" 
if **Morning order Insert** into business timestamp from order table, order_id from order table, "morning"

Required Output for business table for the above order sample:
Business table:

```
2018-06-24 00:00:00,000 l9093klk0333333330 morning
2018-06-25 00:00:00,000 l9093klk0333333331 evening
2018-06-25 00:00:00,000 l9093klk0333333332 evening
2018-06-25 00:00:00,000 l9093klk0333333333 evening
```

Could anyone help us with the sql query to achieve the above insert queries. Please comment if further details are required.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the SQL CASE statement. That will allow you to transform the datetime to the string 'morning' or 'evening'.

Comment: @DavidButtrick morning and evening are values to be hard-coded based on timestamp. we require to check timestamp of order table with evening order and morning order condition and insert the data into our business table.

Comment: And that is exactly what the case statement will do for you.